# initial Values no assigning values to reduxForm

Tags: redux-form

When i am using this.props.streams initial value are getting assiged to redux form . But ._pick is not working as expected but console.log is printing correct values.

render in component

```
render(){
        const initialValues = _.pick(this.props.stream,'title','description');
        console.log(initialValues); 
        return(
              <div>
                <h3>Edit Stream</h3>
                <StreamFrom 
                   initialValues={initialValues}
                   onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
              </div>
        )
    }

redux form 

    render(){
            console.log(this.props);
            return(
              <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)} className="ui form error">
                  <Field name="title" component={this.renderInput} label="Enter Title"/>
                  <Field name="description" component={this.renderInput} label="Enter Description"/>
                  <button className="ui button primary">Submit</button>
              </form>
            )
             
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you want to write "streamfrom"? is it "streamform"?